# Rvest cannot find eq tags

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am currently using R to capture a table of columns. Using Rvest as well as finding its css selector, I am able to extract most of them using the html_nodes or html_table function. However, on some, when the css selector includes "eq(somenumber)", I am not able to extract the data. From what I know this eq tag has something to do with Java, but was wondering if there is a way I can use Rvest to get these tags or if there is another package I can do that.

Comment: Can you provide the link from where you are trying to scrape the data?

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, it is an ancestry.com site https://www.ancestry.com/search/collections/62096/?count=50&marriage=1910&marriage_x=0-0-0                                                                               If you don't have an account, the date variable would just show was year but if you sign in, it will give you the year. I think maybe this has to do why it has an eq tag, but not sure.

Comment: I don't see anything like `"eq(somenumber)"` on that page. What data do you want to extract? `url %>% read_html %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]` gives the complete table with correct column names from that page.

Comment: It works! Thank you @Ronak! I had wanted to get the whole table but did not find a way. This makes it so much easier. The eq was what I had found the htmlattribute to be by using a browser extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the complete table from the link you can use -

```
library(rvest)

url <- 'https://www.ancestry.com/search/collections/62096/?count=50&marriage=1910&marriage_x=0-0-0'

result <- url %>% read_html %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]
result

#  `View Record` Name               `Marriage Date` `Marriage Place` `Certificate Number` `View Images`
#   <chr>         <chr>              <chr>           <chr>            <chr>                <lgl>        
# 1 View Record   Mary Cordey        year            Hall             certificate number   NA           
# 2 View Record   Ralph W Craddock   year            Douglas          certificate number   NA           
# 3 View Record   Charles Courtney   year            Otoe             certificate number   NA           
# 4 View Record   Bessie A Crile     year            Saline           certificate number   NA           
# 5 View Record   Guy Crane          year            Douglas          certificate number   NA           
# 6 View Record   Storpha L Crow     year            Douglas          certificate number   NA           
# 7 View Record   Ernestine Crabtree year            Lancaster        certificate number   NA           
# 8 View Record   Oscar C Croft      year            York             certificate number   NA           
# 9 View Record   Ansil B Crabill    year            Webster          certificate number   NA           
#10 View Record   Belva M Craig      year            Merrick          certificate number   NA           
# … with 40 more rows
```